# how can I store printed result from if statement as a dataframe?

Tags: r

I would like to set the printed result of if statement as a dataframe for later use.

For example,

if I run,

```
for(i in 1:nrow(user)){
 for(j in 1:nrow(user_info)){
     if(user[i,1]==user_info[j,1])
          df<-print(user_info[j,1:3])
  }
}
```

the console shows,

```
1 roles user guest
     1    1    15
2 roles user guest
     2    1    367
3 roles user guest
     3    1    648
```

and when I call 'df' it only shows the last result.

```
 roles user guest
   3     1     648
```

How can I store the full result as a dataframe if I want 'df' to be like this?

```
roles user guest
 1    1    15
 2    1    367
 3    1    648
```

---

In order to clarify the question, here is the sample data.
I tried all comments but the problem is not solved yet..

- `user[user[,1] %in% user_info[,1], 1:3]`: output doesn't matches with the expected one.
- merge and rbind: only store one row, not the full data.

user:

```
roles  action  created_at
  10      1     2016-08-01
  10      1     2016-08-01
  1       1     2016-08-01
  3       2     2016-08-01
  4       1     2016-08-01
  5       1     2016-08-01
  5       2     2016-08-02
  8       1     2016-08-02
  9       1     2016-08-02
  7       2     2016-08-02
```

user_info:

```
roles user guest
  1     1    15
  2     1    367
  3     14   42
  4     2    34
  5     4    2
  6     3    100
  7     23   32
  8     9    49  
  9     55   12
  10    8    291
```

Comment: `user[user[,1] %in% user_info[,1], 1:3]`

Comment: It doesn't seem like this line works...
Is that right that I should replace this line with `df<-print(user_info[j,1:3])` ?

Comment: @WoobinYun You should replace it with your entire loop code.

Comment: @Roland Care to write an answer from your comment?

Answer (score 1):

What about merging?

```
merge(user_info, user, by = "role")[, 1:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try **rbind**?

```
for(i in 1:nrow(user)){
 for(j in 1:nrow(user_info)){
     if(user[i,1]==user_info[j,1])
          user_info<-print(user_info[j,1:3])
          df<-rbind(df,user_info)
  }
}
```